# Realsense R200 Freezing

Tags: ros, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Has anybody had any issues with the realsense (r200) disabling your mouse and keyboard when you plug it in or the computer completely freezing when you try to run the default launch files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244107/realsense-r200-freezing/) by [RogerRabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/28029/rogerrabbit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-09-21**:
I have not observed that. Please update your question with more details. What sort of hardware are you running on? What platform? What sort of load does your machine go to when running the launch files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I actually managed to get it working. My fix was to update my Ubuntu 14.04 kernel from 3.16 to 4.4. I followed the instructions for the Video4Linux backend for step 3 using the 4.4 kernels steps. Hardware wise I am using:

- NVIDIA GTX 745 Video Card
- I7-6700 3.40 GHz CPU
- 32 GB RAM

---

Originally posted by [RogerRabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/28029/rogerrabbit/) with karma: 11 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-09-21**:
Glad it's working. I converted your comment to an answer. I voted up your answer so you should have enough karma to accept your own answer (use the checkmark at the left) so that others know this question is solved.